# Powershell - How to use import-csv for SwitchParameter

Tags: powershell

I have a custom cmdlet written in C# which takes `SwitchParameter` as one of its arguments, I want to execute my cmdlet using import-csv, how should I write my csv so that I am able to pass correct `SwitchParameter` value?

I have tried True, False, 0 , 1, with and without quotes in CSV however they dont seem to work, I always get false in my code

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)]
public SwitchParameter Enable { get; set; }
```

I am running Powershell version 2.0, the command I want to execute is :

```
Import-Csv c:\data.csv | Add-MyData
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Import-CSV`, all properties are `string`-objects. So if you use `0` and `1`, you need to cast it to `int`, and the to `bool`. Ex:

test.csv

```
Name,Enabled
"Hey",1
"Lol",0
```

Script:

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | % { $_.Enabled = [bool]($_.Enabled -as [int]); $_ }
#You could also cast it with [bool]([int]$_.Enabled), I just like to mix it up :)

Name Enabled
---- -------
Hey    True
Lol    False
```

You can then pass that to your switch, like:

```
#My test-func
function testfunc ($Name, [switch]$Enabled) {
    "$Name has switchvalue $Enabled"
    }

Import-Csv .\test.csv | % { 
    $_.Enabled = [bool]($_.Enabled -as [int])
    testfunc -Name $_.Name -Enabled:$_.Enabled 
    }

Hey has switchvalue True
Lol has switchvalue False
```

Comment: Sure I could parse everything, but I isnt there any way powershell does the conversion automatically? I simply want to issue Import-Csv c:\data.csv | add-MyData

Comment: Like I've said. `Import-CSV` imports EVERY value as strings, so you need to cast the values if you need specific types. If you really want to use the command above, then do the casting inside your `add-myData` cmdlet

Comment: I want my cmdlet to accept switchparameter, so I am not willing to make it string for import-csv to work. Given that signature remains switchparameter, what other options do I have? Creating another optional parameter which takes the same information in string format will be confusing, so what else? Is manual parsing my the user the only alternative?

Comment: Why not create a helper cmdlet? Ex. `Convert-myData` that does the conversion. Ex. `Import-Csv c:\data.csv | convert-myData | add-MyData` . or you can make a helper cmdlet that converts and calls the `add-mydata`for you. Ex. `Import-csv c:\data.csv | Import-myData` . That's almost how MS does it in PS. `Export-CSV` and `ConvertTo-CSV` uses the same helperclass that does the job conversion. The only difference is the `Export-Csv` also stores csv as in a file.